# Requested bean is currently in creation

Tags: java, spring

My controller

```
@RestController
public class CheckUserDataRestController {
    private final UserSearchService userSearchService;
    @Autowired
    public CheckUserDataRestController(final UserSearchService userSearchService) {
        this.userSearchService = userSearchService;
    }
...
}
```

initialize bean service

```
@Service("userSearchService")
public class UserSearchServiceImpl implements UserSearchService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final AuthorizationService authorizationService;
    @Autowired
    public UserSearchServiceImpl(
            @NotNull final UserRepository userRepository,
            @NotNull final AuthorizationService authorizationService
    ) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }
...
}
```

which initializes another service bean

```
@Service("authorizationService")
public class AuthorizationServiceImpl implements AuthorizationService {
    private final UserSearchService userSearchService;
    @Autowired
    public AuthorizationServiceImpl(final UserSearchService userSearchService) {
        this.userSearchService = userSearchService;
    }
...
}
```

The following error is thrown during compilation:

```
2018-04-05 02:09:39.024  WARN 1864 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'checkUserDataRestController' defined in file [C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\web\out\production\classes\com\web\web\controller\CheckUserDataRestController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userSearchService' defined in file [C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\core\out\production\classes\com\core\jpa\service\UserSearchServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'authorizationService' defined in file [C:\Users\Jonatan\Documents\GitHub\REST-Web-Services\core\out\production\classes\com\core\service\impl\AuthorizationServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userSearchService': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

The error is caused by the fact that the `UserSearchService` service is autowired simultaneously in the controller and in the `AuthorizationService` service. How do I prevent this error?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that the constructor of `AuthorizationServiceImpl` requires a bean of `UserSearchService` to be wired, which means `UserSearchServiceImpl` will be wired, but the constructor of `UserSearchServiceImpl` requires a bean of `AuthorizationServiceImpl` to be wired (which means that `AuthorizationServiceImpl` will be wired). This dependency is circular and Spring cannot resolve it without help on the part of the developer:

`AuthorizationServiceImpl` → `UserSearchServiceImpl` → `AuthorizationServiceImpl`

One way to break this circular dependency is to inject the `UserSearchService` bean into `AuthorizationServiceImpl` through [setter injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-setter-injection), rather than through [constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-constructor-injection). This allows Spring to create the `AuthorizationServiceImpl` bean without needing to create the `UserSearchServiceImpl` bean. Once the `AuthorizationServiceImpl` has been initialized, the `UserSearchServiceImpl` bean can then be initialized. Once `UserSearchServiceImpl` has been initialized, it can be wired into `AuthorizationServiceImpl` using its setter. This reduces the dependencies to the following:

`UserSearchServiceImpl` → `AuthorizationServiceImpl`

To do this, change `AuthorizationServiceImpl` to the following:

```
@Service("authorizationService")
public class AuthorizationServiceImpl implements AuthorizationService {
    private UserSearchService userSearchService;

    public AuthorizationServiceImpl() {}

    @Autowired
    public void setUserSearchService(UserSearchService userSearchService) {
        this.userSearchService = userSearchService;
    }

    ...

}
```

and `UserSearchServiceImpl` to the following:

```
@Service("userSearchService")
public class UserSearchServiceImpl implements UserSearchService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private AuthorizationService authorizationService;

    @Autowired
    public UserSearchServiceImpl(@NotNull final UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthorizationService(AuthorizationService authorizationService) {
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    ...
}
```

It is important to note that technique requires that the `userSearchService` and `authorizationService` fields be made mutable (the `final` qualifier is removed).

Comment: I thought that what you wrote helped, but no. Today I checked and throws out the error https://pastebin.com/NyFUysQH

Comment: @Super_Koks Understood. Try setter injection with `UserSearchService` as well (so that both have setter injection) and see if that solves the issue. I.e. injection `AuthorizationService` into `UserSearchServiceImpl` through setter injection.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I got assigned to a new existing application at work that had no unit tests.  The app was poorly designed and had a lot of @Autowired strewn throughout the code.  After trying the Constructor initialization of Beans, that created circular references, and your suggestion to go with the Setter method solved my issue.  So, thanks very much!!!

Comment: @tjholmes66 Glad this helped resolve your issue